# Default scopes for the BigQuery AppsScript Client don't include Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been trying to set up a Drive file (sheet) as a federated data source in BigQuery via the API in Apps Script. For some reason, enabling the Drive API from the UI is not really working. I'd still get that the Drive scope is missing.

Any ideas would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just fixed this, here is how in case you're facing this issue. Enabling the Drive API in the UI won't be enough.

In case the app doesn't explicitly call any Drive related API calls in other places, the drive scope won't get added into the script's manifest.

This worked in my case by explicitly enabling the drive scope in the manifest.json file (make sue to select  "show manifest file" in the UI). The scope for drive is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive to be added into the *oauthScopes* list, example:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Dubai",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v3"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "BigQuery",
      "serviceId": "bigquery",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```